# Prove by induction: alternating sum

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction, proof-explanation

I'm trying to prove by induction the following claim:
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{n} i^{2}(-1)^{i+1} = (-1)^{n-1}\frac{n}{2}(n+1)
$$

So far for the proof I have the following:
Let n = 1.
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{n} i^{2}(-1)^{i+1}=1^2(-1)^{1+1}=1
$$ 
  and 
$$
(-1)^{1-1}\frac{1}{2}(1+1)=1
$$

If we assume true at n=k. Then:
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{k} i^{2}(-1)^{i+1}=k^2(-1)^{k+1}
$$

Now, if we let n = k+1. Then:
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{k+1} i^{2}(-1)^{i+1}= 1-4+9-...\pm k^2(-1)^{k+1} \pm (k+1)^2(-1)^{(k+1)+1}
$$

$$
= (-1)^{k-1}\frac{k}{2}(k+1)+(k+1)^2(-1)^{k+2}
$$

This is where I get stuck. I know we want to have this as the final answer, but I can't figure out how to get to this:
$$
=(-1)^{(k+1)-1}\frac{k+1}{2}((k+1)+1)
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: Look at your target: you want the thing to simplify to

$$(-1)^k\frac{k+1}2(k+2)\;,$$

which has a factor of $k+1$. And you have a factor of $k+1$ in your final expression:

$$(-1)^{k-1}\frac{k}2(k+1)+(k+1)^2(-1)^{k+2}=(k+1)\left((-1)^{k-1}\frac{k}2+(-1)^{k+2}(k+1)\right)\;.$$

Since $(-1)^{k-1}=(-1)^{k+1}$, you can also pull out a factor of $(-1)^{k+1}$:

$$(k+1)\left((-1)^{k-1}\frac{k}2+(-1)^{k+2}(k+1)\right)=(-1)^{k+1}(k+1)\left(\frac{k}2-(k+1)\right)\;.$$

If you now simplify the expression in the last pair of parentheses, just a very little more algebra will get you to your goal.

Comment: Could you please explain how (-1)^(k-1) = (-1)^(k+1)?

Comment: @Alisa: $(-1)^{k+1}=(-1)^{k-1+2}=(-1)^{k-1}(-1)^2=(-1)^{k-1}$.

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate all of your help. Maybe I'm just thinking about this too hard, but I do have one final question. How will I end up with (-1)^k in my final answer when I have (-1)^(k+1) in the last part you mentioned? I keep getting (-1)^(k+2)

Comment: @Alisa: Same idea: $(-1)^{k+2}=(-1)^k(-1)^2=(-1)^k$. Remember, $(-1)^n$ is $-1$ when $n$ is odd and $1$ when $n$ is even, so shifting $n$ by an even even amount doesn’t change $(-1)^n$.

Comment: Thank you for all of your help!

Comment: @Alisa: You’re welcome!